# Losing cookies on lotus notes

Tags: javascript, cookies, xpages, session-cookies, lotus-notes

When we logged to system, we create a cookies in the browser to use many times.

[image]

We have a custom control with links to redirect to others bases.

[image: Custom Control here]

When whe gone to another base, the cookies desapear.

I searched on the base any script could be removing the cookie, but dind't find it.

We got a Server side script to works on link click event.

```js
var doc:NotesDocument=database.getProfileDocument("frm_profile",session.getServerName());
var str = doc.getItemValueString("no_base_gft");
var host=context.getUrl().getHost();
var path=context.getUrl().getPath();
var ss= 'http://'+host+"/"+str;

sessionScope.remove("usuarioLogado");
facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(ss);
```

If i put a print in the end of this scrpit, before the redirect, will returns me the var ambiente "d". So, i've been thinking maybe is any script in the other base could be deleting the cookies on load the first page.

Someone passed for the same problem in Lotus notes version 9?

Maybe the Server remove the cookies? That's possible?

Comment: You know, that cookies are only valid for the site that sets them? redirecting to another page means losing the cookies... works as designed...

Comment: If the new url has the same domain, it should work. Compare the domain from ltpatoken and ambiente cookie.